# CakePHP - Multiple paginated tables for the same model, on the same page

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I get the impression this is not supported by Cake core yet, but has anyone managed to write their own code to do so?  Is it possible with Ajax? I don't mind having all my tables Ajax sortable if this is the only way to do it.

Yes, I am aware of the link everyone posts (http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-have-multiple-paginated-widgets-on-the-same-page-with-cakephp) and it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scrapping Cake's pagination system, and instead used a jQuery plugin called dataTables (http://www.datatables.net/).

It is quite frankly amazing what this guy has done to develop the plugin.  It supports server-side powered pagination, sorting, and even filtering of your tables.